# Add a variable to trigger a function in the parent - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to call a function in the parent of a child.

I have created a component I can use on multiple pages in my Vue project, once the function has run I want to call a function on the parent.

I can achieve this by doing `this.$parent.getLocations()` - and it works.

However as this is a component I need `getLocations()` to be a variable this could be `getPets()` or `getLunch()` for example.

I am passing through `'Location'` to the component so I can use that.

I have tried: `'${this.$parent}.get${this.type}s()}'` (`this.type` being `Location`) and `this.$parent + ".get" + this.type +" s()`

However neither trigger the function.

How do I make `getLocations a variable to run the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an anti pattern. The child of the parent should not know about the parent's function.

In the child:

```
this.$emit('needs-locations', { type: this.type })
```

In the parent:

```
<child @needs-locations="getLocations" :locations="locations">

getLocations(type) {
  api.then((locations) => this.locations = locations)
}
```

This will give you bidirectional communication without dependency.

Answer (score 1):

First you emit an event from the child to the parent, and you pass a type to it.

```
this.$emit('runFunction', type)
```

Then handle the event:

```
<child-component @runFunction="handleRunFunction"/>
```

On the parent runFunction would look like this:

```
handleRunFunction(type) {
        switch (type) {
            case 'Location':
                getLocations();
            case 'Pets':
                getPets();
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

A normal if-else statement works equally well.